# How to fix the NoReverseMatch error in Django at /auth/password_change/?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

When you click on "Change password" an error appears:

> NoReverseMatch at /auth/password_change/
> Reverse for 'tabel_list' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['groups/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']

header.html

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link {% if view_name  == 'schedules:tabel_list' %}active{% endif %}"
    href="{% url 'schedules:tabel_list' student.group.slug %}"
    >
    Расписание
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Модульный журнал</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Библиотека</a>
  </li>
{% endif %}
```

schedules/views.py

```
@login_required
def tabel_list(request, slug_group):
    DAY_WEEK_LIST = ({
        'MONDAY': 'Понедельник',
        'TUESDAY': 'Вторник',
        'WEDNESDAY': 'Среда',
        'THURSDAY': 'Четверг',
        'FRIDAY': 'Пятница',
        'SATURDAY': 'Суббота',
        'SUNDAY': 'Воскресенье',
    })
    group = get_object_or_404(Group, slug=slug_group)
    tablets = Tablet.objects.filter(group=group)
    username = request.user.username
    student = Student.objects.get(student_id__username=username)
    day_week_en = []
    set_day_week = []
    for lesson in tablets:
        if lesson.day_week not in day_week_en:
            day_week_en.append(lesson.day_week)
    for day_en in day_week_en:
        set_day_week.append(DAY_WEEK_LIST[day_en])
    context = {
        'tablets': tablets,
        'group': group,
        'set_day_week': set_day_week,
        'student': student,
    }
    return render(request, 'schedules/tabel_list.html', context)
```

schedules/urls.py

```
``from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'schedules'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('groups/', views.group_list_all, name='groups_list_all'),
    path('groups/<slug:slug_group>/', views.tabel_list, name='tabel_list'),
]`
`
```

users/urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import (LoginView, LogoutView,
                                       PasswordResetView, PasswordChangeView,
                                       PasswordChangeDoneView,
                                       PasswordResetDoneView,
                                       PasswordResetConfirmView,
                                       PasswordResetCompleteView
                                       )
from django.urls import path
from . import views


app_name = 'users'
from django.contrib.auth.views import (LoginView, LogoutView,
                                       PasswordResetView, PasswordChangeView,
                                       PasswordChangeDoneView,
                                       PasswordResetDoneView,
                                       PasswordResetConfirmView,
                                       PasswordResetCompleteView
                                       )
from django.urls import path
from . import views


app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.SignUp.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path(
        'logout/',
        LogoutView.as_view(
            template_name='users/logged_out.html'),
        name='logout'
    ),
    path(
        'login/',
        LoginView.as_view(
            template_name='users/login.html'),
        name='login'
    ),
    path(
        'password_change/',
        PasswordChangeView.as_view(
            template_name='users/password_change_form.html'
        ),
        name='password_change'
    ),
    path(
        'password_change/done',
        PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(
            template_name='users/password_change_done.html'
        ),
        name='password_change_done'
    ),
    path(
        'password_reset/',
        PasswordResetView.as_view(
            template_name='users/password_reset_form.html'
        ),
        name='password_reset'
    ),
    path(
        'password_reset/done/',
        PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
            template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'
        ),
        name='password_reset_done'
    ),
    path(
        'reset/<uid64>/<token>/',
        PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
            template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'
        ),
        name='password_reset_confirm'
    ),
    path(
        'reset/done>/',
        PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
            template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'
        ),
        name='password_reset_complete'
    ),
]
```

models.py

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Название группы',
        max_length=15,
    )
    institute_name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Название института',
        max_length=50,
    )
    institute_name_short = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Краткое название института',
        max_length=20,
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(
        verbose_name='slug группы',
        unique=True,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group_name


class Student(models.Model):
    student_id = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='ID студента',
        related_name='student_id'
    )
    group = models.ForeignKey(
        Group,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='group_id',
        verbose_name='Группа',
    )
    form_training = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Форма обучения',
        max_length=20,
        choices=FORM_TRAINING_LIST,
        default='PAID',
    )
    last_name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Фамилия',
        max_length=20,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.student_id}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Студент'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Студенты'
```

Link
path('groups//', views.tabel_list, name='tabel_list'),
it works fine (available only for authorized users). I don't understand what the problem might be, since slug_group is not passed in the link to change the password. I've seen a lot of responses on this error, but I can't apply this to my project.

Comment: I assume the `Student`'s instance does not contain any value for `group`  or that group does not have any slug. You should check the DB.

Comment: @ruddra Added models, maybe they are a problem

Comment: It's not about models, it's about actual data stored in tables. Not all of your users are students or not all students have link to a group or some of groups are missing slug value - if any of these is true the error will appear. Also this code is in the `header` template, I guess it is included in many other templates. This means that all the views providing data for these templates must provide `student` value. If they don't - the error will appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are using `header.html` in many templates and not in all of those templates have the context variable named `student`. Hence you can create a custom [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) like this:

```
#context_processors.py
from .models import Student

def student(request):
    """
      The context processor must return a dictionary.
    """
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
       stdnt = Student.objects.get(student_id__username=request.user.username) 
    else:
       stdnt = None
    return {'student':stdnt}
```

Finally add it in settings:

```
#settings.py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        #under OPTIONS key
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                #context processor written by us.
                'appname.context_processors.student'
           ],
        },
    },
]
```